# Replace values of one array based on a mapping array

Tags: php, arrays, mapping

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = [29, 'a', 'x', 'c', 11];
$array2 = ['a' => 20, 'x' => 21, 'c' => 23];
```

I want to get an array that looks like:

```
$array3 = [29, 20, 21, 23, 11];
```

I know how to do it with a foreach loop, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it as a one liner, or maybe with some sort of anonymous function.

Comment: `array_walk($array1, function(&$value) use ($array2) { $value = isset($array2[$value]) ? $array2[$value] : $value; } );` or `array_walk($array1, function(&$value) use ($array2) { $value = $array2[$value] ?? $value; } );` for PHP>7.0

Comment: @MarkBaker yep, that's pretty good. cheers. I like the php7! if you post as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: No, I used the comment by @MarkBaker, `array_walk($array1, function(&$value) use ($array2) { $value = $array2[$value] ?? $value; } )`

Answer (score 2):

You can add them and filter out non-numeric values:

```
$array3 = array_values(array_filter($array1 + $array2, 'is_numeric'));
```

If the order is important:

```
$array3 = array_filter(call_user_func_array(
                       'array_merge', array_map(null, $array1, $array2)), 
                       'is_numeric');
```

Then `array_values` if you need to re-index.

In either case, if you want only integers or floats then use `is_int` or `is_float`.

Comment: yep, I would like to remove the keys I don't need

Answer (score 2):

array_map work as well the other answer :

```
$array1 = [29, 1=>'a', 2=>'x',3=>'c', 11];
$array2 = ['a'=>20, 'x'=>21, 'c'=>23];

$array3 = array_map(function($a) use($array2){return is_int($a) ? $a : $array2[$a];}, $array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

An attempt with a one-liner :

```
$array1 = [29, 1=>'a', 2=>'x',3=>'c', 11];
$array2 = ['a'=>20, 'x'=>21, 'c'=>23];

$array3 = array_values(array_filter(array_merge($array1,$array2),function($i){return is_int($i);}));

print_r($array3);

// Outputs :
/*
Array
(
    [0] => 29
    [1] => 11
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 21
    [4] => 23
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon this looks more elegant than the earlier posted solutions...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LI2qC))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => $array2[$v] ?? $v, $array1)
);
```

Attempt to access the mapping array's value by key; if there is no matching key, then default to the original value.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like to use `foreach()` you can use `array_replace()` function. You can learn more about this function in below:

[Array_replace($array1 , $array2, $...) in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)